# Using a link inside p/h:panelGrid columns

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, commandlink

I'm using `<p:commandLink>` inside `<p:panelGrid>` as follows.

```
<p:panelGrid columns="1" style="width: 50%;">
    <p:commandLink>
        <h:outputText styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search"/>
    </p:commandLink>

    <p:commandLink>
        <h:outputText styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search"/>
    </p:commandLink>

    <p:commandLink>
        <h:outputText styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search"/>
    </p:commandLink>
</p:panelGrid>
```

In this case, the area surrounded by columns inside `<p:panelGrid>` as shown in the following picture is clickable in its entirely

[image]

but it is not the case of Internet Explorer (8) in which case, the only clickable item is the link icon as indicated by the `styleClass` attribute of `<h:outputText>`.

Is there a way to make entire columns of `<p:panelGrid>` clickable on Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to let an element span the entire table cell, the element in question needs to have CSS `display` property set to `block`. In this particular case, this is already set via `.ui-icon` class on the `<span>` element as represented by `<h:outputText>`. However, the `.ui-icon` in turn defines a background image. IE incorrectly attaches the background image to the parent element instead of the current element. You need to set the parent element to `display:block` as well, which is in your case the HTML element as represented by `<p:commandLink>`.

E.g. this should do:

```
<p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="search">
    <p:commandLink>
        <h:outputText styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search"/>
    </p:commandLink>

    <p:commandLink>
        <h:outputText styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search"/>
    </p:commandLink>

    <p:commandLink>
        <h:outputText styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search"/>
    </p:commandLink>
</p:panelGrid>
```

With

```css
table.search {
    width: 50%;
}
table.search a {
    display: block;
}
```

This shouldn't affect the behavior in real browsers.